# React native share base64 image on Telegram

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to take a screenshot of a screen area and share the image (on base64) on Telegram, but on IOS I have an infinite load, and on android I share file like "1223123.null"

```js
const format = Platform.OS === "android" ? "raw" : "png";

const saveImage = () => {
    captureRef(viewShooter, {format, result: 'data-uri', quality: 0.7}).then(
        async uri => {
            const shareOptions = {
                type: 'image/jpeg',
                message: 'поРепимся',
                title: 'поРепимся',
                url: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'file://' + uri : uri,

            };

            Share.open(shareOptions).then(() => console.log('Successfully shared')).catch(() => console.log('Failure'))
            dispatch(setMakeImage(false))
        },
        error => console.error("Oops, snapshot failed", error)
    );
}
```

```js
[...]

<ViewShot ref={viewShooter} style={styles.imageButton}  options={{format: 'png', quality: 0.7}}>

[...]
```

Also, I checked [this](https://github.com/react-native-share/react-native-share/issues/737) issue, but these solutions didn't helped me at all.